# Is it possible to integrate multiple front end apps, one in vue and another in react, with a single laravel backend?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I have inherited a laravel code base that has a vue app integrated with it(inside resources/assets/js) through laravel-mix. I am asked to develop some front-end feature with react. I want to know if I can configure webpack.mix.js and the laravel routes so that the react app can be integrated into the laravel app without affecting the vue application.

Comment: In general: yes, it's possible. You can provide single API and consume it by both Vue and React apps.

Comment: This is not a Laravel limitation.  When creating a Laravel project, it allow selection/preset support for Angular, React, Vue, or whatever...  Your project is in Vue so I suggest you learn Vue instead of mixing it.  Though, if you insist, you can mix Vue and React like so: https://github.com/akxcv/vuera

Comment: @Noogen the vue app happened to be unrelated to the react app I am working on. My goal was to add my react feature without touching the vue app that was already there. And yeah, mixing them in one feature is probably a bad idea. So, I was actually able to do exactly what I wanted. I simply had to tell laravel-mix to compile the respective js and css files to separate destinations, give them separate routes in the web.php, link the js and css files appropriately in the blade templates, put their source codes in separate js and sass folders within resource/assets, and it all worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

So here is how I resolved my own question, and successfully integrated two separate react apps, and one vue app against a laravel backend.

Updated my `webpack.mix.js` file as follows:

```
mix
  .react("resources/assets/js-calendar/app.js", "public/js-calendar")
  .sass("resources/assets/sass-calendar/app.scss", "public/css-calendar")
  .react("resources/assets/js/app.js", "public/js")
  .sass("resources/assets/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
  .js("resources/assets/js-vue/app.js", "public/js-vue")
  .sass("resources/assets/sass-vue/app.scss", "public/css-vue");
```

The content of my `resources/assets` folder was:

```
├───js
│   └───components
├───js-calendar
│   └───components
├───js-vue
│   └───components
├───sass
├───sass-calendar
└───sass-vue
```

Had the following three blade templates in my `resources/views` folder:

```
app.blade.php  hello.blade.php  welcome.blade.php
```

And the content of web.php file was:

```
Route::view('/calendar/{path?}', 'app');
Route::view('vue/{path?}', 'hello');
Route::view('/{path?}', 'welcome');
```

And finally the compiled css and js files were linked in the blade files like this:

```
...
    <link href="{{ asset('css-calendar/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js-calendar/app.js') }}"></script>
....
```

The above was for the `app.blade.php`. For the hello.blade.php the css and js src links respectively were `css-vue/app.js` and `js-vue/app.js`. And for the `welcome.blade.php`, the src links were `css/app.css` and `js/app.js`.

Notice how `yarn run dev` generates the respective css and js files in separate destinations:

```
/js-calendar/app.js    9.45 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js-calendar/app
                                             /js/app.js    2.14 MB       1  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app
                                         /js-vue/app.js    1.43 MB       2  [emitted]  [big]  /js-vue/app
                                  /css-calendar/app.css     219 kB       2  [emitted]         /js-vue/app
                                           /css/app.css     219 kB       2  [emitted]         /js-vue/app
                                       /css-vue/app.css     219 kB       2  [emitted]         /js-vue/app
```

I had both `vue` and `react` dependencies and their entries added to the `package.json`.